# PHP if statement: if an element equals at least one element from array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I'm wondering what are the correct syntaxes to execute such a code in PHP:

```
array = ['a','b','c','d']

<?php

if element = 'a' or 'b' or 'c' or 'd':
    echo something

?>
```

and when you have more values in your array… something like:

```
array = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']

<?php

if element = one of the values from the array:
    echo something

?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
if (in_array($element, array('a','b','c','d'))) {
     // The value of $element is a, b, c, or d
}
```

Comment: I think this is a world record, like: answered a question within 15 sec or so

Comment: Or `array_search` if you need the key instead.

Comment: thanks! but I was actually looking for something that helps when you've got a huge amount of values in your array.

Comment: Well, actually, John Conde had almost replied *before* I posted the question, thanks to him!